# Can I create an Xcode workspace "target" programmatically using Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I can create targets using the Xcode UI, but I want to create new Xcode workspace targets for different apps, programmatically.

I was told this was possible using CocoaPods, but I have come to suspect this is not true. Can anyone provide guidance?

There is a library which CocoaPods itself uses, which I may try:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj